# Importing text file of ints into R list

Tags: r, list

So I am new to R programming, and I am simply looking how to import a text file with a ton of random numbers on separate lines into an R list like such:

```
numbers <- c(list_of_numbers.txt)
```

How would this be possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend deleting this question, reading the help center info: http://stackoverflow.com/help, and then asking a new code based question.  As it stands this provides no data or working code; grounds to be closed.

Comment: Have you tried looking up how to import data into R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than doing the conversion your self, it would be better to use

```
numbers <- scan("list_of_numbers.txt")
```

That will create a numeric vector by default.

Although typically it's more common to read in tabular data from delimited files (like csv files) which can be accomplished with the `read.table()` and related functions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a list or a vector?

For a vector, this should do:

```
numbers <- as.numeric(readLines(con="test.txt"))
```

If you really want it as a list with single elements, you could do this afterwards:

```
numbers <- as.list(numbers)
```

(or `as.list(as.numeric(readLines(con="test.txt")))`...)